# C# GUI Chicken, Farmer, Grain, Fox Game

Tags: c#, user-interface

Is there any way to access the images in a FORM class via another class?

Ex;

```
Form1 f = new Form1( );

If (f.chickPicBox1.Visible && f.foxPicBox1.Visible)
{
    Eat = “ATE CHICKEN”;
}
```

I have to do a GUI program based on the riddle the Farmer, Chicken, Grain and fox. I’m using images and moving them (changing visibility) from one bank to another.

We’re supposed to have a Form class and a class that assesses if a person wins or loses.

Any help would be appreciated! 
(I would copy my whole code but I’m on my phone as I have no internet here).

Comment: Yes, there is. But it is also the completely wrong way. The rule is that the game state (wich of the 3 states the chicken, grain and fox are in; where the Farmer is) should be in the code behind. The UI should only be a represnetation of those values. If you start by trying to extract any information from the UI (except for rare User inputs), you will only get into issues.

Comment: Ok, what would be the best way to do this? Should I move what I have into the Form itself?

Comment: The chicken, grain and fox can each be in one of 3 states: Side A, Side B, attached to/carried by the Farmer. Each side has 3 display Spots (one for each of the 3 items). If all 3 items are on side B, the player wins. If Items 1+2 or 2+3 are on the same side without the Farmer being there (to pick up 2), the player looses. The Farmer can be at Side A, Side B or in-between (transit?). So some basic Integers or enumerations in Arrays can store this.

Comment: As a general Advice, GUI technologies like WindowsForms are not really suited for Game Development. Anything more then a turnbased single/hotseat multiplayer game with minimal animations and you run into issues. Solitaire was basically the top of what is possible here. Usually you want something with a GameLoop of some sort. Howevert this sounds like Homework, so you might be stuck with using Windows Forms.